# Same color bar for multiple surfaces in ILNumerics PlotCube

Tags: c#, winforms, ilnumerics

I plot multiple surfaces in one plot cube. But I cannot make them to have the same color bar. I have defined an ILColorbar and added them to the surfaces but it plots two color bars with different numbers. Is it possible for the both surfaces to have the same color bar? Moreover, how can I add text to the color bar (title, labels)? Thank you very much. Here is an example:

```
    private void ilPanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var scene = new ILScene();
        // add a new plot cube 
        var pc = scene.Add(new ILPlotCube());
        pc.TwoDMode = false;
        // Create Data
        ILArray<float> A = ILSpecialData.torus(0.75f, .25f);
        ILArray<float> B = ILSpecialData.torus(3.0f, .65f);
        // Add the surface
        var sf1 = new ILSurface(A);
        var sf2 = new ILSurface(B);

        pc.Add(sf1);
        pc.Add(sf2);
        sf1.Colormap = Colormaps.Jet;
        sf2.Colormap = Colormaps.Jet;

        var cb = new ILColorbar();
        sf1.Add(cb);
        sf2.Add(cb);
        ilPanel1.Scene = scene;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them use the same `DataRange`. I use `UpdateColormapped()` on the surfaces to provide the same `Tuple<float,float>`. This tells them which colors from the colormap to use. For some reasons I could not use the corresponding `ILSurface` constructor. This might be a bug? (Someone should file an issue in that case ?)

The colorbar is modified just like any other object: you can add new shapes / labels to it the regular way. Use the `Padding` property, in order to make more room for your labels:

```
private void ilPanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var scene = new ILScene();
    // add a new plot cube 
    var pc = scene.Add(new ILPlotCube(twoDMode:false));

    // Create Data
    ILArray<float> A = ILSpecialData.torus(0.75f, .25f);
    ILArray<float> B = ILSpecialData.torus(3.0f, .65f);
    // Add the surfaces
    var cdr = Tuple.Create<float,float>(-0.6f, 0.6f);  
    var sf1 = new ILSurface(0);
    var sf2 = new ILSurface(0);
    // provide the same datarange to both surfaces
    sf1.UpdateColormapped(A, dataRange: cdr);
    sf2.UpdateColormapped(B, dataRange: cdr);

    pc.Add(sf1);
    pc.Add(sf2);
    sf1.Colormap = Colormaps.Jet;
    sf2.Colormap = Colormaps.Jet;

    var cb = new ILColorbar() {
        Padding = new SizeF(10,30),
        Children = {
            new ILLabel("Title") {
                Position = new Vector3(.5f,.1f,0),
                Anchor = new PointF(.5f,.7f),
                Font = new Font(DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold)
            },
            new ILLabel("Label") {
                Position = new Vector3(.12f,.5f,0),
                Rotation = -Math.PI / 2,
            }
        }
    };
    sf1.Add(cb);
    ilPanel1.Scene = scene;
}
```

[image: torus with plot cube and custom data range]

You probably are aware of the fact, that you do not have to use a plot cube at all? If we add the torus right below `scene.Camera` we get a torus without distortion:

[image: Torus with no distortion]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to add the plotcube to the camrea so that it keeps the shape? What I want is to plot surface to some sort of plot cubes with axises which show the ranges but at the same time keep the shape of the surface without distortion. I am trying to code it myself and add it the camera but I have not been successful so far.