# How to set common datarange for multiple ILContourPlot?

Tags: ilnumerics

I have a ILPlotCube that has three different ILContourPlot.

```
this.scene = new ILScene();
ILPlotCube pc = new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false);

ILArray<float> TA = tempRoom.GetILArray("TA");
ILContourPlot cpa = new ILContourPlot(TA, create3D: false) {new ILColorbar(), new ILLegend()};
ILArray<float> TB = tempRoom.GetILArray("TB");
ILContourPlot cpb = new ILContourPlot(TB, create3D: false) {new ILColorbar(), new ILLegend()};
ILArray<float> TC = tempRoom.GetILArray("TC");
ILContourPlot cpc = new ILContourPlot(TC, create3D: false) {new ILColorbar(), new ILLegend()};

pc.Add(cpa);
pc.Add(cpb);
pc.Add(cpc);
scene.Add(pc);
ilPanel1.Scene = this.scene;
ilPanel1.Refresh();
```

When I add ILLegend and ILColorbar to these ILContourPlots, I get three of each and all three have different dataranges (eg. plot1: red = 50, plot2: red = 100, plot3: red = 150).

How can I set these ILContourPlots to use same datarange (eg. Min=0, Max=200)?

Essentially I want same thing as in this question but ILContourPlots don't have UpdateColormapped-method and dataRange-property:
[Same color bar for multiple surfaces in ILNumerics PlotCube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107818/same-color-bar-for-multiple-surfaces-in-ilnumerics-plotcube)

EDIT: I could add dummy min and max values for wanted datarange to each ILArray but that is kind of a ugly fix and it also messes up contours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the overload of `ILCountourPlot` which takes a collection of contour level specifications and define each level explicitely:

```
ILArray<float> A = ILMath.tosingle(ILSpecialData.terrain);
panel.Scene.Camera.Add(new ILPlotCube("SO", twoDMode: false) {
    Children = {
        new ILGroup(translate: new Vector3(0,0,10)){
            new ILContourPlot(A["0:250;0:250"], new List<ContourLevel>() {
                new ContourLevel() { Value = 1000, LineWidth = 3, LineStyle = DashStyle.Dotted  },
                new ContourLevel() { Value = 3000, LineWidth = 3, LineStyle = DashStyle.Dotted },   
                new ContourLevel() { Value = 4000, LineWidth = 3, LineStyle = DashStyle.Dotted },   
                new ContourLevel() { Value = 5500, LineWidth = 3, LineStyle = DashStyle.Dotted },   
            }) { new ILColorbar() }
        },           
        new ILContourPlot(A["150:400;150:400"], new List<ContourLevel>() {
            new ContourLevel() { Value = 1000, LineWidth = 3 },
            new ContourLevel() { Value = 3000, LineWidth = 3 },   
            new ContourLevel() { Value = 4000, LineWidth = 3 },   
            new ContourLevel() { Value = 5500, LineWidth = 3 },   
        })
    },
    Projection = Projection.Perspective,
});
```

[image]

Note, you couldeven define individual colors for each contour level. However, doing so would obviously destroy the relation between contour level values and the color within the colormap. THerefore, once your start specifying individual colors, the contour plot will not be considered as "colormapped" anymore and the colorbar will not show.

Here, since we have only picked *values* for the contour levels, the corresponding color from the colormap will be picked and the mapping values <-> colors is still intact.

Contour plot documentation: http://ilnumerics.net/individual-contour-levels-configuration.html

Comment: Can't quite get it to work, I'm giving same List<ContourLevel> to each ContourPlot (List has 50 contourlevels, smallest is 1 and biggest is 50) and it results in situation like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q52hpgofpp8pkrk/ilnum.JPG

Comment: Are you sure the dataranges for your plots really overlap? Reduce your code and post a minimal runnung example!

Comment: Dataranges of plots don't overlap (first is 5-15, second 16-25, third 40-50). I'll post example in hour or two.

Comment: Totally horrible example: http://pastebin.com/H0qiFRTM
This produces three different colorbars and color-ranges when using same contourlevel-list for each of the contourplots.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, this is not possible with the current version. Please file a new feature request in the bugtracker: http://ilnumerics.net/mantis The addition of an option for specifying (color)dataranges for contour plots is pretty simple. There is good chance it can be done soon. Thanks!